# Saving PDF to OneDrive using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, onedrive

My company started using Microsoft Office 365.  They are using OneDrive to save and view files.

I have been tasked to build a website that will allow customers to upload files directly into OneDrive.  My team has created our own OneDrive dummy account to test saving the files that will be uploaded by a customer.

Starting with simple HTML form input:

```
<form id="uploadfile">
  <input type="file" id="pdfFile" name="pdfFile" class="form-control" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="uploadBtn">Upload File</button>
</form>
```

And now the jQuery:

```
$('#uploadBtn').on('click', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($('#uploadfile')[0]);  // <-- not currently using this variable, but I know I will need it
  var filename = $('#pdfFile').val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, '');

  var odOptions = 
  {
    clientId: "00000000-xxxxx-0000-xxxx-0000000000",
    action: "upload",  // <-- was originally set to save
    sourceInputElementId: "pdfFile",
    sourceUri: "",
    fileName: filename,
    openInNewWindow: true,
    advanced: {endpointHint: "api.onedrive.com"},
    success: function(files) { /* success handler */ },
    progress: function(p) { /* progress handler */ },
    cancel: function() { /* cancel handler */ },
    error: function(e) { /* error handler */ }
  }
  OneDrive.save(odOptions);
});
```

All of the above is coming from the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/save-file

### Edit

I have made some progress since asking this. I can get to the point to where the OneDrive window opens, and I can see various folders.  But it seems there is no file for me to save.

Starting here:

[image]

The user has selected an image.  Upon clicking the upload button, the OneDrive opens:

[image]

But when I am inside the OneDrive window, upon clicking the save button, no file is saved.

What am I missing that will get the file to save into the OneDrive?

Comment: Have you checked if your regex is working as you expected?

Comment: I am able to see the filename, if that is what you're asking.

Comment: You probably didn't put it in your code because the guide you yourself mentioned says it is required, so it should be obvious, but asking it nonetheless, are you importing the OneDrive script the way it is mentioned in the guide?

Comment: Or maybe this could be related to the size of your file. Since you're not explicitly defining the size limit in your script, it could be the reason it won't work. Or "#pdfFile" is being repeated somewhere.

Comment: I made an update to the code.

Comment: (This question has a related and possible duplicate [sister question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628677/saving-pdf-to-onedrive-using-jquery-part-2), which readers may wish to read before answering this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to save to OneDrive.  Some adjustments were made on the Application Registration Portal (where you retrieve your appID).  I added permissions to ensure that I could read/write to the folder in OneDrive.

I also made adjustments to the odOptions portion of the code:

```
$('#uploadBtn').on('click', function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  //var formData = new FormData($('#uploadfile')[0]); 
  //var filename = $('#pdfFile').val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, '');

  var odOptions = 
  {
    clientId: "00000000-xxxxx-0000-xxxx-0000000000",
    action: "save",  // upload was not valid
    sourceInputElementId: "pdfFile",
    //sourceUri: "", 
    //fileName: filename,
    openInNewWindow: true,
    advanced: {endpointHint: "api.onedrive.com"},
    success: function(files) { /* success handler */ },
    progress: function(p) { /* progress handler */ },
    cancel: function() { /* cancel handler */ },
    error: function(e) { /* error handler */ }     
  }
  OneDrive.save(odOptions);
});
```

Following the documentation here helped solved my problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/save-file